# Need photo of each contact in the phonebook

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am very much confused in getting a photo related with contact stored in address or phonebook.
All i find is ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI and get cursor from it .
And use this cursor to get all details about particular contact.But it is not giving me photo attach with that contact .

I also try ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO , and it loads blank bitmap each time .

Can anyone give me clear way of getting photo of a contact .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the id of the contact the code would look like this:

```
     Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
     InputStream inStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ctx.getContentResolver(), contactUri);
     }
     Bitmap bm = null;
     if (inStream != null) {
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
     }
```